# How to compare Datetime field with SystemTime.now() in SOQL query

Tags: datetime

I have a 2 datetime field(Start_Time__c and End_Time__c) and I need to compare them with current time.
I am writing the following SOQL Query :

Select id from objTime where Start_Time__c >= SystemTime.now() AND End_Time__c

But it is unable to fetch to the comparison of date time, do we have any solution for resolving the same ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use static or dynamic SOQL here. 
It would be as below

Static soql:

```
DateTime currentTime = System.now();
List<Account> accounts  = [SELECT Id From Acccount WHERE Start_Time__c >= :currentTime AND End_Time__c <= TODAY ];
```

Dynamic soql:

```
DateTime currentTime = System.now();
```

`List<Account> accounts = Database.query('SELECT Id From Acccount WHERE Start_Time__c >= :currentTime AND End_Time__c <= TODAY ');`

I tried this on account , you can use this on any sobject.
As a common practice if this helps mark this as solution.

Comment: Note that this approach works using static SOQL too as static SOQL supports the same binding syntax.

Comment: Yes keith, this approach works with static queries too. Now a days I got addicted to dynamic queries more oftern. :P

Comment: OK, then surely the answer is "you can bind the current time into a static or dynamic SOQL query"; the choice of static or dynamic is unrelated to the question.

Comment: Hi,I am still having issue when I use the compare Start_time__c>= system.now() ; see below for the exception that I am getting USER_DEBUG|[140]|DEBUG| ************************* currentTime =  2015-11-23 17:13:42
11:13:42.616 (616612307)|VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Exception encountered, please contact administrator.

Comment: @Amit please post your code.

Comment: as per your above code you forgot to put : (colon) before system.now(). Please check that.